# How to exclude certain values from a Query [SQL]

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, having-clause, subquery

as the title states, an `NotPrimID`, **can** have two different values `Example 1` and `Example 2`

```
"ExampleTable"

NotPrimID     Text
0             "Example 1"
0             "Example 1"
0             "Example 2"
1             "Example 1"
1             "Example 1"
2             "Example 1"
2             "Example 2"
```

IF: if `NotPrimID` does have both values, it should be automatically excluded from the query result.

**What i want:** Query, that will deliever all the `NotPrimID`, that only have "Example 1" as a result, **however** if `NotPrimID` does have "Example 2" also as a possible result, it should be automatically excluded.

**Question:** How to exclude certain `NotPrimID`, if it does have additional values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select notprimid
from exampletable
group by notprimid
having min(text) = max(text) and min(text) = 'Example1'
```

This returns all `notprimid`s that have only one distinct `text`, whose value must be `'Example1'`.

Comment: Works fantasticly - Thank you!